# Certificate generation with Keytool, I can't confirm personal data

Tags: linux, cygwin, ssl-certificate, openssl

I'm trying to generate a **self-signed certificate** in order to sign some source code. I use:

```
keytool -genkey -storepass mypass -alias lorenzos -keystore nbproject/private/keystore
```

Then I fill in personal data, but every time I confirm them, it asks me personal information again and again:

```
Specificare nome e cognome
 [Unknown]:  Lorenzo Stanco
Specificare il nome dell'unità aziendale
 [Unknown]:  N/A
Specificare il nome dell'azienda
 [Unknown]:  N/A
Specificare la località
 [Unknown]:  Modena, Italy
Specificare la provincia
 [Unknown]:  MO
Specificare il codice a due lettere del paese in cui si trova l'unità
 [Unknown]:  IT
Il dato CN=Lorenzo Stanco, OU=N/A, O=N/A, L="Modena, Italy", ST=MO, C=IT è corretto?
 [no]:  yes
Specificare nome e cognome
 [Lorenzo Stanco]:
[...]
```

I've tried also using `None` instead of `N/A`. I've got the same problem on my Ubuntu machine and on my Cygwin terminal in Windows.

Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Does `keytool -genkeypair -dname "cn=Mark Jones, ou=JavaSoft, o=Sun, c=US" -alias business -keypass kpi135 -keystore  working/mykeystore -storepass ab987c -validity 180` work? or even just `keytool -genkeypair`?

Comment: @soandos The first one works and creates the file. The second one asks me for a password, then asks for personal details, and goes forever as I described above.

Comment: Can you just edit the first to fit what you are trying to do?

Comment: @soandos I'm trying. I let you know if it works when I test the certificate.

Comment: @soandos It worked. If you post an answer with that command line I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use: `keytool -genkeypair -dname "cn=Mark Jones, ou=JavaSoft, o=Sun, c=US" -alias business -keypass kpi135 -keystore working/mykeystore -storepass ab987c -validity 180` with the appropriate substitutions (change the name, date, etc, if you want).